# Send management a copy of the promotional email for each language

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, email-studio

is there an easy way to send the management team a copy of the promotional send for each possible language?

Using the CC/BCC feature isn't an option as this will send them 800k copies per send.

Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way is to add the management people for all the language into your data extensions and send it.

Comment: You can have like a seed list DE which includes this data, and add this DE to every send also